# AppCompat Resources In Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to access resources usually found under **android.support.v7.appcompat.R**

in Android in Xamarin.Android by following conventions they should be found under 
**Android.Support.V7.AppCompat**

in Xamarin.Android. However, All could find under this name space was the **BuildConfig** class

I'm using the **version 27.0.2.1** of the 
**Xamarin.Support.V7.AppCompat** package and API level 27

Can anyone help me finding out how I could access those resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AppCompat Resources In Xamarin

In native android, you could find the `AppCompat` resources via:

```
android.support.v7.appcompat.R.anim.abc_fade_in
```

In `Xamarin.Android`, you could directly find these resources under `Resource` namespace, eg:

```
Resource.Animation.abc_fade_in

or

yourprojectname.Resource.Animation.abc_fade_in
```